PyQt6 crushes when used with multiprocessing and compiled into .exe
import multiprocessing as mp

class MainWindow(BaseWindow):
    def __init__(self, app: QApplication, ui: Ui_MainWindow) -> None:
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(app, ui)
        self.pool = mp.Pool(initializer=init_logging)

in here
self.pool = mp.Pool(initializer=init_logging) part causes the application to multiply itself and eventually crush the windows when I compile it to .exe with this script below.
@echo off
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --icon "epey.ico" --add-data "log_config.json;." --add-data "JSONFormatter.py;." --distpath ./dist "main.py"
del main.spec
pause

if I run it with python main.py everything is fine though.
What I tried:

I tried to remove:

def init_logging():
    log_dir = Path("logs")
    if not log_dir.exists():
        log_dir.mkdir()

    if getattr(sys, "frozen", False) and hasattr(sys, "_MEIPASS"):
        config_file = Path(sys._MEIPASS) / "log_config.json"  # type: ignore
    else:
        config_file = Path("log_config.json")
    with open(config_file) as f:
        config = json.load(f)

    logging.config.dictConfig(config)
    queue_handler = logging.getHandlerByName("queue_handler")
    if queue_handler is not None:
        queue_handler.listener.start()  # type: ignore
        atexit.register(queue_handler.listener.stop)  # type: ignore

I though maybe this causes the problem in self.pool = mp.Pool(initializer=init_logging) because when I compile the program into .exe, it gets the log config from temp file (sys._MEIPASS) but it didn't work.
What I expected

A program that doesn't multiply itself, opens only one window, and functions normally.


How could your software crush the windows? It would need some physical actuator to do it.

@Elerium115 it kept spawning the same app until my cpu couldn't handle it and crushed.

I'm sorry to hear that your CPU has been damaged beyond repair.

@1tsimple The term is crash, "crush" has completely different meanings.

Ok, after some research. Apparently this is a windows specific thing. In multiprocessing on Windows, when a new process is spawned, the entire script is re-executed (as opposed to being forked like on Unix systems) which results in creating the PyQt app over and over again in my case. In order to fix this, you need to add mp.freeze_support() like this:
import multiprocessing as mp    

if __name__ == "__main__":
  mp.freeze_support()
  main()

